# Installing Appium 1.3.4 in terminal from .tgz

Tags: node.js, terminal, appium

I have a tarball Appium (CLI version) package stored locally and I'd like to install it using terminal.

Prior to this I would run `npm install appium` pull and install it, but now I'd like to be able to install it without necessarily having network access.

What is the procedure to install it from a .tgz using terminal?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, open terminal, secondly use the command **cd** to navigate to the correct folder. If there is a README file with installation instructions, use that instead.
extract the files with one of the commands

If it's tar.gz use *`tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz`*

if it's a tar.bz2 use  `*tar xvjf PACKAGENAME.tar.bz2 ./configure*`

```
*make sudo make install*
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!